# Taging and conditional autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, tags

I'm using http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/ for taging and autocomplete. As of right now, I can autocomplete for a single term:

Console:

```
GET .../source.php?term=value01
```

Javascript:

```
$("#input-newsearch-2").tagit({
singleField: true,
singleFieldDelimiter: ",",
allowSpaces: true,
autocomplete: ({
  source: function( request, response ) { 
    //var tagterm = $('#input-newsearch-2').val(); 
    $.ajax({
      url: "source.php",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        //term: tagterm
        //term: $('#input-newsearch-2').val()
        term: request.term
      },
      //data: JSON.stringify({ term: $('#input-newsearch-2').val() }),
      success: function( data ) {
        response( data );
      }
    });
    console.log( request.term );
  },                        
    minLength: 3,
    select: function(event,ui){

    }

})

});
```

... when hitting key enter the value gets tagged ( alert($('#input-newsearch-2').val() = value01) ) and I can search for the next term.

But when entering the next term, autocomplete searches the whole database each time again. I would like to filter the database considering the previous tags (AND WHERE)? How is this possible?

This is my html:

```
<input id="input-newsearch-2" autocomplete="off" type="text">   
// created by tagit                                                                                                                     
<ul class="tagit ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
<li class="tagit-choice ui-widget-content ui-state-default ui-corner-all tagit-choice-editable">
<li class="tagit-new">
    <input class="ui-widget-content ui-autocomplete-input" autocomplete="off" type="text">
</li>
</ul>
```

... when I've tagged multiple values #input-newsearch-2 looks like:

```
$('#input-newsearch-2').val() = value01,value02,value03
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean, you want to concatenate the new entered value to the previous entered value(s)?

You could concatenate the new entry to a globally declared variable.

```
// before/outside of tagit()...
var terms="";
```

If the global variable has a length>0, then add a comma then the new entry, otherwise don't add the comma.

```
// concatenate when you wish:
if(terms.length>0){
    terms+=',';
}
$terms+=$('#input-newsearch-2').val();
```

Then just add the global variable to ajax's data object, and the csv string should be delivered.

```
  data: {
    term: terms
  },
```

Alternatively, you could concatenate new entries to an `<input name="termstorage" type="hidden" value="">` element, and just have your ajax's collect that value.

I suppose in either instance, you'd also want to offer the ability to clear previous entries from memory.

---

Here is the php query build part...

I am making the assumption from your other recent/associated question that you are filtering against db columns: `name` & `code`

Also, any values entered by the user containing a comma will impact the query. Always, always sanitize user input.

This code uses a loop purely to demonstrate how three different inputs will generate different queries.  The loop will not be necessary in your actual case since your input is a single string.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00494860a597c25a09bc49f7d04bc324f1b937c0))

```
$mock_GET_term[]="";
$mock_GET_term[]="value01";
$mock_GET_term[]="value01,value02,value03";

foreach($mock_GET_term as $csv){
    $query="SELECT * FROM `accounts`";
    if(strlen($csv)>0){
        $where_cond=str_replace(',',"%' OR `name` LIKE '%",$csv);
        $query.=" WHERE (`name` LIKE '%{$where_cond}%'";
        $query.=" OR `code` LIKE '%{$where_cond}%')";
    }
    echo "Query = $query\n\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Query = SELECT * FROM `accounts`

Query = SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%value01%' OR `code` LIKE '%value01%')

Query = SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%value01%' OR `name` LIKE '%value02%' OR `name` LIKE '%value03%' OR `code` LIKE '%value01%' OR `name` LIKE '%value02%' OR `name` LIKE '%value03%')
```

Comment: @PhilippM If this answer satisfies, please mark it as accepted, otherwise leave me a comment to explain what isn't quite right and I'll have another crack at it.  Let's keep moving this question toward resolution.